# Unable to update the listView in Android

Tags: android

I have a ListView which displays 5 listitems. When the user selects the last item (5th item), a hit goes to server and the next set of 5 items is displayed.

I have implemented the code for displaying the first 5 items. I am also able to fetch the next set of items from the server, but the items are not updated in the ListView.

If required I can share the sample code.

Kindly provide hints/sample source code.

Comment: Whenever you ask for help, source code will go very far into getting help with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try clearing the list items first and then update the list elements?
In order to commit the updates you should call notifyDataSetChanged() ..

Comment: yes lalith ... I can share the source code with you ... if you want ?.. infact getView method() .... class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter ... the count is 10 .. which means that the data is available but its not displayed properly .. I have also called the notifyDataSetChanged .. Kindly provide your inputs if you have already done something similar